# Choosing a .NET Framework version

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, versioning

When I build a project, should I use the earliest possible .NET version (so that it can run on older systems) or the latest (so that it is the most up to date and stable)? What sort of things should I consider?

Comment: Picking a version of freely available software that anybody can install, and can install itself today, should never ever constrain you.  The only thing that matters is whether you *really* want to support customers that have not upgraded their operating system in the past 7 years.  A cranky lot that don't like to deal with change.  Your program is change, they'll be cranky about it.

Comment: I feel like we need more information to adequately answer this question.  What are you trying to build, who is your target audience, and what are your goals/priorities?   Those answers factor into the recommendation.  I think to simply ask which version "in general" is too broad to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends solely on what your clients will have available and what they are willing to install.

Also - all .NET versions are equally stable. Newer ones just have more features for you to use as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on many factor; like what you are trying to do in your project. If you are trying to use features like WCF/WPF you will have to use version3.5 or higher.

Again, if you building a web application (ASP.NET) probably you have no dependency with client since client just need a browser who can talk to the web server but if you are doing a Winform/Windows based application then you will also have to consider what your client have.